# Ember.js Testing async action in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've a controller with an action that invoke a method that do some async stuff and return a promise.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  _upload: function() {
    // return a promise
  },
  actions: {
    save: function(item) {
      this._upload(item).then(function(response) {
        // Handle success
      }, function(error) {
        // Handle error
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I would like to unit test the code under `Handle success` and `Handle error`.
In my unit test I've mocked the `_uploadMethod` using

```
controller.set("_upload", function() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve({name: "image1"});
  });
});
```

And then I invoke the action and assert that the success handler has done is job

```
controller.send("save", "item");
assert.equal(controller.get("selected.item"), "item");
```

The problem is that the assertion fails because it's run before the promise is resolved and all the stuff in success handler is completed.

How can I wait the promise to resolve before the assertion is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try this instead:

```
controller.set("_upload", function() {
  const promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve({name: "image1"});
  });

  promise.then(() => Ember.run.next(() => {
    assert.equal(controller.get("selected.item"), "item");
  }));

  return promise;
});

controller.send("save", "item");
```

A bit hacky way, but it might work.

Answer (score 1):

To test async methods, you can use the test helper `waitUntil` to wait for the expected return of the method, like the code below.

```
 controller.send('changeStepAsyncActionExample');                                   
 await waitUntil(() => {                                                     
   return 'what you expect to the Promise resolve';                                
 }, { timeout: 4000, timeoutMessage: 'Your timeout message' });

 // If not timeout, the helper below will be executed

 assert.ok(true, 'The promise was executed correctly');
```